# Sorting a PHP array, with strings of keys, manually?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, key

I want to sort my array which contains names as keys and numbers as values, a function for each of sorting by key and by value.

I'm aware of asort() and ksort(), but I want to do this manually. Originally I tried bubble sort, but quickly realised it didn't work as the keys were strings, not numbers.

How would I go about doing this? So if I have the array:

```
$ar = array("A" => 10, "D" => 25, "G" => 12)
```

How would I sort the array by value and by key? I can't find a way of cycling through it and sorting the two different values.

Comment: What the result do you expect for the array in the question?

Comment: Whatever the result of the original asort() would be. So it would sort the values in order from lowest to highest.

Comment: EDIT:
The same applies to what ksort() would produce, so it would sort the above array into alphabetical order by keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code may be use full.

```
$ar = array("A" => 10, "D" => 25, "G" => 12,'B'=>11);

function bubbleSortValues($array){ // sort by value
    $new_array = array_values($array); // get array values
    $length = count($new_array);
    // perform buuble sort
    for ($outer = 0; $outer < $length; $outer++) {
        for ($inner = 0; $inner < $length; $inner++) {
            if ($new_array[$outer] < $new_array[$inner]) {
                $tmp = $new_array[$outer];
                $new_array[$outer] = $new_array[$inner];
                $new_array[$inner] = $tmp;
            }
        }
    }
    // loop the sorted array and generate original array with keys and values
    foreach($new_array as $key=>$value){
        $sorted_array[array_search($value, $array)] = $value;
    }

    return $sorted_array;
}

function bubbleSortKeys($array){ //sort by key
    $new_array = array_keys($array); // get array keys
    $length = count($new_array);
    // perform buuble sort
    for ($outer = 0; $outer < $length; $outer++) {
        for ($inner = 0; $inner < $length; $inner++) {
            if ($new_array[$outer] < $new_array[$inner]) {
                $tmp = $new_array[$outer];
                $new_array[$outer] = $new_array[$inner];
                $new_array[$inner] = $tmp;
            }
        }
    }
    // loop the sorted array and generate original array with keys and values
    foreach($new_array as $key=>$value){
        $sorted_array[$value] = $array[$value];
    }

    return $sorted_array;
}
echo "<pre>";
$values = bubbleSortValues($ar);
print_r($values);

$keys = bubbleSortKeys($ar);
print_r($keys);
```

OUT PUT:

```
Array
(
    [A] => 10
    [B] => 11
    [G] => 12
    [D] => 25
)
Array
(
    [A] => 10
    [B] => 11
    [D] => 25
    [G] => 12
)
```

Comment: Will this work if the keys are "asd", "frr", "k", "Asd", etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use [strcmp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php) to compare strings.